# Reading a specific line of a csv file based on "ID"

Tags: csv, netlogo

I have a NetLogo model and I would like to assign values to patches from a .csv file. The patches have a certain value that I want to use as an "ID" and if "item 0" in a line of that .csv file matches the ID, the rest of the values in the line would be assigned to the patches with that ID.

I made a workaround that creates invisible turtles for each line in the files and then assigning the values is no problem, but is there a way to do this directly using just the csv file?

EDIT: Here's what the workaround does, first opens a file and then creates "helper" turtles like this:

```
 while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let data csv:from-row file-read-line
    create-turtles 1 [
      set xcor 0
      set ycor 0
      set size 0
      set color 0
      set HPJid item 0 data
      set A item 1 data
      set B item 2 data
      set iC item 3 data ] ]
```

Then I can just use:

```
ask patches [ let helper one-of turtles with [HPJid = HPJ of myself]
set D [A] of helper
set E [B] of helper
set F [C] of helper ]
```

Then all works, but I'd like a way to do this without the turtles.

Comment: I'm afraid don't understand what the turtles or for, or what the difficulty would be in doing without them. (Including code in your question might help?)

Comment: As I said, the turtles are a workaround since I haven't found a way to do it with what the csv extension is capable of. I have a patch variable, let's call it ID that matches to the first item of a row in the csv file and I need to assign the rest of the values in that row to the patches. Different patches have different IDs that correspond to a different row in the data file. If I create the turtles, I can just assign the values from turtles to patches with no problems by matching ID of patch and ID of the turtle but I don't know a way of doing that with just the csv file.

Comment: so why can't you just read in a line, get the first element (say, it is X), then `ask one-of patches with [ID = X] [ series of set statements ]`? You need to give us csv data and your workaround code if we are to have any hope of understanding where you're stuck

Comment: Damn, I didn't think of doin it the other way around, reading the csv file first row by row and asking patches with matching ID to change their values accordingly. Not only this might actually work, but it looks like it might also be much more time effective. Thanks @JenB, you've just helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, having looked at your code, I think you can simply do:

```
while [ not file-at-end? ]
[ let data csv:from-row file-read-line
  let in-ID item 0 data
  ask one-of patches with [ID = in-ID]
  [ set var1 item 1 data
    set var2 item 2 data
  ]
]
```

or something like that anyway - with appropriate variable names of course